# Central list of SMART on FHIR endpoints

Tags: hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I am building a [SMART on FHIR](https://smarthealthit.org/smart-on-fhir-api/) app for patient mediated EHR analysis.

Is there a centralized list of SMART on FHIR endpoints? For example, [Epic provides this list of endpoints](https://open.epic.com/MyApps/Endpoints), and a very nice [patient facing website to access Epic MyChart for a particular clinic](https://www.mychart.com/LoginSignup). It is searchable by location. So I can search for "Maryland" and see all clinics with MyChart for that state.

I seek to replicate the Epic MyChart access page, but add SMART on FHIR endpoints from eClinicalWorks, Cerner, and other vendors. I think a central and continually updated list of SMART on FHIR endpoints would be beneficial to EHR interoperability - especially if it were open source and updated frequently. The information is all public, it would be a matter of compiling it and keeping it updated. Is there such a list that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now we are working on a specification to provide more consistent publication of endpoint and branding information to help patients select their provider. We are aiming to have each vendor openly publish more complete data in a consistent format. From there, compiling a centralized list should be possible.

Feel free to check out https://hackmd.io/@argonaut/patient-access-brands for details.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not quite what you're after, but I wanted to point out that [Lantern](https://lantern.healthit.gov/?tab=dashboard_tab) aggregates published FHIR API endpoints and some details about them.